# Long exposure shots using "T" function on GX80/85 and ImageApp

Tags: panasonic-lumix, panasonic

Has anyone managed to find a way of using the "T" long exposure setting on the GX80/85 via ImageApp? 
I want to record long star trails, so the default 60 second long exposure is not quite long enough. 
Manually holding down the shutter for 120 seconds is tricky (as there's no remote shutter cable facility), so an ImageApp solution would be ideal!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple really! In ImageApp select the "T" option from the shutter settings.
Click the record item once to start recording. Click record item again if you want to stop before the full time is up! I'd been trying something less obvious (don't ask!). The simple approach is often the best!